# What is the meaning of dots in some of the Apex's cards?

Tags: android-netrunner

Some apex's cards from the Data and Destiny have dotted pattern (for exaple [Harbinger](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09034)). What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a flavour text written in ITA2

> Harbinger: I AM BECOME DEATH
>
> Apocalypse: THE DESTROYER OF WORLDS

It's a reference to famous J. Robert Oppenheimer quote